# Stripe::Customer instance has invalid ID: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm having some difficult implementing stripe payments on my rails app. I want to redirect the user to a new payment page for confirmation, and then to finalize the payment in a create action.

I'm getting the error:

> Stripe::InvalidRequestError in PaymentsController#create
>
> Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe::Customer instance
>   has invalid ID: nil

payment_controller.rb

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @user = current_user

        token = params[:stripeToken]
        @customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :source => token,
            :email => @user.email   
        )
    end

    def create
        @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(params[:customer_id])

        begin
            charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                :amount => @product.amount, #amount in cents, again
                :currency => "eur",
                :description => params[:stripeEmail],
                :customer => @customer.id
            )
        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
            # The card has been declined
            body = e.json_body
            err = body[:error]
            flash[:error] = "Unfortunately, there was an error processing your payment: #{err[:message]}"
        end
    end
end
```

payments/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Thank you for using our services.</h1>

<p>
    You (<%= @user.email %>) have ordered the <%= @product.name %>.
</p>

<div class="payment_info">
  <p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @product.name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Description:</strong>
    <%= @product.description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Colour:</strong>
    <%= @product.colour %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Price:</strong>
    <%= '%.2f' % (@product.amount/100.00) %>
  </p>
 </div>

<%= form_for(@payment) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, @product.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :customer_id, @customer.id %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', product_path(@payment.product) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should upgrade to the latest stripe api version. Stripe has guidelines on there website found under ["api upgrades".](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades?since=2017-04-06#api-changelog)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `params[:customer_id]` is nil and stripe could not determine / prepare the URL to invoke the stripe server.

You need to make sure the `params[:customer_id]` is not `nil`